# Projectile's Range

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

There is a projectile launched from earth. It has an elliptical orbit unless it hits again earth. It has reached to apogee point then hit again Earth. I know initial, hit and Apogee point velocities. I calculated the time of projectile's duration of flight and launch angle. How can i find the range of projectile on Earth.

I searched a little bit. There are some answers to that but they assume Gravity is contast. In my problem gravity is not constant.

Given : $V_a$ = 1000 m/s

initial velocity and hit velocity $V_h$ = 4000 m/s

Found = Radius of apogee $r_a$

With conservation of angular momentum equation flight path angle

With $$r(\theta) = (h^2/Mu) \cdot 1/(1+e.\cos(\theta))$$

theta represents true anomalies, h angular momentum, Mu = Mass of Earth and Gravitational constant

I found $e$, eccentricity, with using $\theta = 180^{\circ}$.

then I found with same eq. theta initial and hit point true anomalies.

I calculated semi major axis length with the help of same equation using $\theta = 0$ point of apogee.

I calculated $T$, period

With using true anomalies I found eccentric anomaly then time between them.

Comment: When you say "gravity is not constant" you mean, presumably, it is a function of height of the projectile? But that's the assumption for the elliptical orbit. Can you not determine the shape of the ellipse - and thus where the object will hit earth again? If it helps at all - the long axis of the ellipse will pass through the center of the earth... I am puzzled by your "assume earth is flat plane" statement. That would suggest the range of the projectile is small - and in that case why would you worry about changing gravity? Please clarify.

Comment: But if you already have the duration of the flight, can't you just multiply the horizontal velocity by that time?

Comment: @Floris the horizontal velocity is changing by time because of elliptical orbit's properties. (For example : At perigee, max velocity, at apogee, min velocity.) Actually i don't know range of projectile is small or big. 
Yes i am doing that assumption because if the projectile didn't hit the Earth, It will rotate around Earth with elliptical orbit.
Forget the "assume Earth is flat plane" because i think the range means in the question saying us to trajectory of the object untill the hits the Earth.

Comment: I deleted my comment.  I apologize that it sounded rude, that was not my intent.  I think I typed too fast without considering what I wrote.  But please tell us what you have tried so we can help you get past the point where you get stuck.

Comment: @garyp i edited the question, you can check. thank you for warning.

Comment: Does the Earth rotate? (BTW how did you get the time of flight? That is far more difficult than calculating the point of return.)

Comment: @sammygerbil no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

The orbit is an ellipse - and because it was launched from the surface of the earth, it WILL hit the earth again.

You have enough information to calculate the semimajor axis (using the vis viva equation). This axis goes through the center of the earth.

You know the initial velocity, and velocity at apogee. The gravitational potential follows a $\frac{1}{r}$ law. That is enough to get the maximum height of the projectile (from conservation of energy).

Now you have everything you need to draw the elliptical orbit, and the intersection of that orbit and the circle (centered on a focal point of the orbit)

**UPDATE**

Since you found the anomalies, the following diagram should tell you trivially what the range is:

[image]

Obviously, $2\alpha + \phi = 2\pi$.

Comment: yes i found everything you said. i know the true anomalies still couldn't get how to find the arc between them.

Comment: We use energy conservation and angular momentum conservation. But then I am unable to see how we can find either the \phi or \alpha. It is kinda difficult to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

The. orbits have been sketched by Newton for different velocities at a given angle of projection. Quantities $p, \epsilon $ of classical ellipse $ p = r + \epsilon x $  with Earth center as one focus are expressed in terms of angle projected, projectile speed, mass of earth. Velocity less than escape velocity makes re-entry and re-hit with earth possible when no wind resistance is taken into computation.